# UserWarning when adding descriptive information to a dataframe that is an attribute

Tags: python, pandas, class, getattr

I have multiindex dataframe that is actually an attribute and I am looking to store the index names using the following command:

```
getattr(self, attrdfname).__idxnames__ = getattr(self, attrdfname).index.names
```

It raises the following error:

```
UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name
```

Found some answers around but it's not very clear how I could avoid the warning.

I could obviously call the below command whenever I need it but as I have several dataframes stored as attributes, I would like to store these dataframes 'attributes' to my dataframe.

```
getattr(self, attrdfname).index.names
```

Anyone knows how to work around it?